# Moviesdb api not working

Tags: android, themoviedb-api

Can anybody check is the following api is working for you in a asyntask operation?

https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/550?api_key=#

You must have an api_key valid to try it.

The problem that I am getting is, the link is working in a browser but when I run it in Android, it is giving me a status message error 34,the resource you requested could not be found.

Comment: u can service down questions here

Comment: Can you share the code for the asynctask?

Comment: I just want to try it on your side... is it possible to do it?